# Add Animated Line in Mesh Animation

Tags: javascript, css, sass, css-animations

How could I add animated lines in this sample mesh animation?

HAML / HTML

```
%div.wrap
  -300.times do
    %div.c
```

CSS/SCSS

```
// best in chrome
$total: 300; // total particles
$orb-size: 100px;
$particle-size: 2px;
$time: 14s; 
$base-hue: 0; // change for diff colors (180 is nice)

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: black;
      overflow: hidden; // no scrollbars.. 
    }

    .wrap {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 0; 
      height: 0; 
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      perspective: 1000px;
      animation: rotate $time infinite linear; // rotate orb
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
      100% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(360deg);
      }
    }

    .c {
      position: absolute;
      width: $particle-size;
      height: $particle-size;
      border-radius: 50%;
      opacity: 0; 
    }

    @for $i from 1 through $total {
      $z: (random(360) * 1deg); // random angle to rotateZ
      $y: (random(360) * 1deg); // random to rotateX
      $hue: ((40/$total * $i) + $base-hue); // set hue

      .c:nth-child(#{$i}){ // grab the nth particle
        animation: orbit#{$i} $time infinite;
        animation-delay: ($i * .01s); 
        background-color: hsla($hue, 100%, 50%, 1);
      }

      @keyframes orbit#{$i}{ 
        20% {
          opacity: 1; // fade in
        }
        30% {
          transform: rotateZ(-$z) rotateY($y) translateX($orb-size) rotateZ($z); // form orb
        }
        80% {
          transform: rotateZ(-$z) rotateY($y) translateX($orb-size) rotateZ($z); // hold orb state 30-80
          opacity: 1; // hold opacity 20-80
        }
        100% {
           transform: rotateZ(-$z) rotateY($y) translateX( ($orb-size * 3) ) rotateZ($z); // translateX * 3
        }
      }
    }
```

https://codepen.io/natewiley/pen/GgONKy

Desired animation:

[image]

Comment: Why is this a Haml question? Haml only generates a page, it doesn't write JavaScript.